# R software installation sudo apt-get install R

Tags: software-installation

How  to install R software in ubuntu using terminal codes. I tried using `sudo apt-get install R` ?

Comment: What ddid apt-get result in? Because it should work if the software is available in your software sources. So add their ppa to your sources.

Answer (score 1):

`R` is in the universal repository, so you will need to enable that in your "Software and Updates" package. To enable that, type "software and updates" in your dash and open the application that comes up. Go to "Ubuntu software" and let there a check mark on "Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)". Type your password, if prompted to and then close this window.

Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
```

---

Source: [The Ubuntu R Blog](http://www.personal.psu.edu/mar36/blogs/the_ubuntu_r_blog/installing-r.html)

Answer (score 0):

The correct command for installing `R` is

```
sudo apt-get install r-base-core
```